# Java regular expression to split string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I've been trying to build a pattern in Java to split the following string by dashes AND by tab characters. The exception is that if a dash appears after a tab has already been encountered in the string, even once, we stop splitting on the dash and only split on tabs. For example:

Input string (those big spaces are tab characters):

```
"4852174--r-watch   7   47  2   0   80-B    20  5"
```

Expected output: `["4852174", "r", "watch", "7", "47", "2", "0", "80-B", "20", "5"]`

I'm using the following regular expression so far: `"(?<!\\d)(\\-+)(?!\t)|\t"`

The first set of brackets to signal I don't want any numbers preceding the delimiter, the next to signal that I want one or more dashes, and the last set to note that I want no tabs to follow. Of course, the OR at the end is for splitting by single tab characters.

The result that I'm getting is the following:
`["4852174-", "r", "watch", "7", "47", "2", "0", "80-B", "20", "5"]`

Notice the extra dash in the "4852174-" that should not be there. I've tried for very long to try to figure this out but any small change I make ruins the splitting elsewhere.

Any help to solve this problem would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: just to clarify, my knowledge regarding regex is not that good however this might be useful to someone. Sir do you want to split it from one or more dashes ? if so why do you except `80-B` as an output ?

Comment: The remaining dash is preceded by a digit, so it won't get matched (the `(?<!\d)` part of your regex). It seems to me that you're missing some rules that you would need. Could you answer: why should `80-B` not be splitted?

Comment: Just a clarifciation: how did you use this regex in the code? I'm not seeing your output on regexplanet.com. Did you use String.split()?

Comment: @Manbearpig: There is no tab after dash in `80-B` so why should that not split?

Comment: Check [`(?:[^\s-]|(?<=\d)-(?=[^\W\d]))+`](http://regex101.com/r/wO5hW8). I thought about matching instead of splitting. I think that your rules aren't well defined so I just made it "work" for the input you've provided.

Comment: OP here. My rules, as you guys noticed, were incorrect. I've since updated them in case someone else encounters this question in the future and is looking for a solution. I've been trying to use .split() and it wasn't working for any solution presented so far but using @HamZa's regular expression with pattern/matcher, it works! Thanks.

Comment: Try this regex in Java: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\-]{2}\\-[\\s\\S]{1})|([^\\-\\s])+"); It worked for me: use matcher.group(0) to get the expected output. Declare an arraylist to store the values sequentially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex

```
\t|-+(?!\w\t)
```

will split the string into your desired array, but without further clarification what you want to do I can not tell you if it will work for other Strings.

You can test regex at [www.regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Ct%7C-%2b%28?!%5Cw%5Ct%29&input=4852174--r-watch%097%0947%092%090%0980-B%0920%095) (This is with your regex.)

Please note that you have to escape the backslash in Java. So in Java it will be

```
\\t|-+(?!\\w\\t)
```

Comment: It will also not split `A-B\t` not sure if OP meant this.

Comment: This worked, using .split()! Thank you a whole bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The regex for matching your string is: **^(([^-\s]+?)[-\s]*)+$**

The above regex will match your string even if hyphens(-) are repeated more than twice. You can get the expected output by obtaining matches from group 2 (\2).

group 1 matching: (([^-\s]+?)[-\s]*)

**group 2 matching: ([^-\s]+?)   => this is the grouping you will need for constructing your output.**

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried ^(([^-\s]+?)[-\s]*)+$ using pattern/matcher and it didn't work for the dashes. Nor for .split().